# Powershell foreach loop is not reaching the end of the array it is given

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon Stack Overflow,

I have a powershell script written to move files from a large SharePoint document library into folders based on the file metadata for allowance of security controls (as it was missed before I did the migrations to SharePoint).

Currently the script terminates after the first 2500 items (roughly) when I need it to process 220,000 items, expecting it to move roughly half of those.
I've checked and the $items variable does contain the entire 220k that I'm expecting but for some reason it terminates earlier than I want it to.

If anyone can spy why, or can recommend best practice to ensure the loop completes (or just in general as my code is often a bodge job being a self taught beginner) it would be much appreciated.

I have left out the full URL but it is present in the script.

---

```
$source = "HR_STAFF"
$targetHR = "HR_STAFF/School Section - Human Resources"
$targetHRContract = "HR_STAFF/Human Resources - Contractual"
$targetContract = "HR_STAFF/Category - Contractual"
Connect-PnPOnline -Interactive -Url $SiteURL

$items  = Get-PnPListItem -List $source -PageSize 1000

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    
    if ($item.FieldValues.SER_SchoolSection -eq "Human Resources" -and $item.FieldValues.SER_Category -eq "Contractual") {
        $sourcefile = $item.FieldValues.FileRef
        $targetfile = $targetHRContract + "/" + $item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $sourcefile -TargetUrl $targetfile -Force
        Set-PnPListItem -Identity $item -Values @{SER_IssueMonth = $item.FieldValues.SER_Modified; Modified = $item.FieldValues.SER_IssueDate; Created = $Item.FieldValues.Created} -UpdateType SystemUpdate
    }
    if ($item.FieldValues.SER_SchoolSection -eq "Human Resources"  ) {
        $sourcefile = $item.FieldValues.FileRef
        $targetfile = $targetHR + "/" + $item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $sourcefile -TargetUrl $targetfile -Force
        Set-PnPListItem -Identity $item -Values @{SER_IssueMonth = $item.FieldValues.SER_Modified; Modified = $item.FieldValues.SER_IssueDate; Created = $Item.FieldValues.Created} -UpdateType SystemUpdate
    }
    if ($item.FieldValues.SER_Category -eq "Contractual"  ) {
        $sourcefile = $item.FieldValues.FileRef
        $targetfile = $targetContract + "/" + $item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $sourcefile -TargetUrl $targetfile -Force
        Set-PnPListItem -Identity $item -Values @{SER_IssueMonth = $item.FieldValues.SER_Modified; Modified = $item.FieldValues.SER_IssueDate; Created = $Item.FieldValues.Created} -UpdateType SystemUpdate
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the ```for``` loop. I don't really know sharepoint, but is it possible an auth token is expiring after, say, 1 hour? Maybe add some timestamp logging and see if the "about 2500 items" correlates to a specific time period. Also log the name of the current item at the start of the ```for``` loop and see if it only iterates over the first 2500 items, or if it actually loops through all of them but does nothing with items 2501-250,000.

Comment: @mclayton thank you for the debugging recommendations. I'll see what happens with those. The auth token seems like an excellent potential solution although the transcript didn't suggest anything. I'll see if I can set authorisation to be through an app registration instead.